# How does Youtube make their embedded videos on facebook fallback to html5 on iOS?

Tags: facebook, video, youtube, share

On Desktop, Youtube's emebedded videos on Facebook are FLASH. On iOS, they become HTML5. How can I do the same for my videos when people share them from my website?

I can have the FLASH version working, but I can't make it fallback to HTML5. On iOS, my videos embedded on FACEBOOK just can't play. Instead, FACEBOOK opens a new window to my webpage.

I have no problem with html5 fallback on my own website. But on FACEBOOK, how can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your problem with them sharing links to player-specific versions of your videos, or with your videos actually getting served from facebook's servers rather than your own?

Comment: If you go to any youtube video page, copy the url from the address bar and post it to your Facebook timeline, you'll see that video is embedded on your timeline. You can directly play it on your timeline, and you'll see it's flash when on desktop and html5 when on iOS. How?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty services for that, just do a quick search on the internet, there are services like this:

http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/

it tracks if the browser/os could read flash, if able then play it, if not then play html5

Most aren't free though

Comment: Sorry, should've made it more clear. On my website I can achieve html5 fallback. But I don't know how to make it when people share my videos on Facebook.

Comment: Unless they are uploading the video files to facebook, your server can still do detection and decide what to actually send.

Comment: If the video is served from my webpage, yes. But my problem is the embedded video on facebook. I have no control to facebook's page. I'm curious about why Youtube's video can fall back to html5.